# confict between the subfigure and customized caption(side-by-side subfigures)

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

the desired result:[image: desired result]

Q:The .cls document i used is a template for a journal IJCAS, i want to use the subfloat package to reveal the side-by-side subfigures,

1，when the subfig package is loaded， Message:! LaTeX Error: Command \setcaptionmargin already defined.Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \caption@setmargin}

2，when the subfig package isnot loaded, of course, the undefined message will apear.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{IJCAS}
%% include the useful LaTeX packages:
%\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \subfloat[topology1]{
   \includegraphics[scale=1]{1}
   }

   \subfloat[topology2]{
   \includegraphics[scale=1]{1}
   }
   \caption{Interaction topology}
   \end{figure}

   \clearafterbiography\relax
    \end{document}
```

the needed document: [IJCAS.cls](https://github.com/MaZhengg/Simulation/blob/master/IJCAS.cls)

Thoughts: the customized caption in IJCAS.cls conficts with the subfig package(in my opinion), is there any way to fix it ,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IJCAS` document class contains a build-in version of the (obsolete) `caption2` package which is incompatible to the `subfig` package. (The actual version of `caption2` can be used with `subfig` so it's a shame that they integrated `caption2` support by copy+paste instead of `\RequirePackage{caption2}`.) So the only way to get the `subfig` package working is writing the maintainer of the `IJCAS` document class that it would be nice if she/he could drop all of the copied and modified `caption2` code and replace it with `\RequirePackage{caption}` and regular adaption of the caption style using documented methods offered by the recent version of the `caption` package.

As alternative one could use the (obsolete) `subfigure` package which is compatible to the (old) version of `caption2` package build-in in `IJCAS`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{IJCAS}
%% include the useful LaTeX packages:

\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \subfigure[topology1]{%
   \includegraphics[scale=1]{1}
   }
   \subfigure[topology2]{%
   \includegraphics[scale=1]{1}
   }
   \caption{Interaction topology}
\end{figure}

\clearafterbiography\relax
\end{document}
```

Comment: IT WORKS! thank you so much. Now i need to submit the manuscript before the deadline, i will fix it in your way! Later, i'll try to email the chief editor to  state the problem! anyway, thanks!